# How to pass multiple functional components in react route?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have something like this,

```
<Switch>
 <Route path="/playground/:id">
      <Header></Header>
      <Playground></Playground>
      <Footer></Footer>
 </Route>
<Switch/>
```

I want to pass all the functional components through the component props like this,

```
<Route path="/playground/:id" component={Playground}></Route>
```

But here I am only able to pass one component through the component props. How could I pass them all?

I want to do that because while passing the functional component through the component props, I can get the `match.params.id` value but when I pass the functional components by the first way, I cannot get the value of `match.params.id` and simply gives the error. `params undefined

So, the first question, How to pass multiple components?
And second question, Why I cannot access value of from match.params.id and how can I access although if I use the first way to pass the components?

Comment: You probably want/need to use the [render prop of Route](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func).

Answer (score 2):

1.You can stuff all all the elements into one component and transfer it to the router

2.To take some kind of value from the params one of the ways is to use the react-router-dom can be taken like this through the useParams hook in as stated in below

```
const { id } = useParams()
console.log(id)
or
const query = useParams()
console.log(query.id)
```

Comment: what about getting id value in other components, rather than main component?

Comment: Yes, you can also take it through hooks from anywhere. I corrected answer